# Adding frequency counts in a dataframe in R by age group

Tags: r

I have data in a dataframe at the moment that looks like this:

```
AgeGroup Med1 Med2 Med3 Med4 Med5 ...

1     "A1" "A2" "C4" "D3" "E3" ...

3     "A2" "C5" "9"   "6"  "9" ...

2     "A1" "C2" "6"   "6"  "9" ...

1      "6"  "6" "A3"  "B4" "9" ...

2      ...........................

4      ...........................

thousand more rows  just like the above
```

There are four age groups and 20 med variables. 
All I want is to sum of the counts for each row by medication and by age group. So the final result would contain the following information:

```
 AgeGroup  "A1" "A2"...."E1" "E2" ... "9" "6"

 1          4    6  .... 0     1  .... 40 20

 2          0    ...........................

 3          ................................

 4          ................................
```

I understand how to use the apply function to sum over rows but in this case I want to sum multiple frequencies over all rows according to age grouping. Is there a way to do this simply?

Comment: try looking into `tidyr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example data based on the format of yours

```
df <- data.frame(AgeGroup=c(1,1,2),
             Med1=c("A1","A2","A1"),
             Med2=c("A2","C5","C2"),
             Med3=c("C4","9","6"),
             stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Use `dpylr` and `tidyr` to convert your data to long format using `gather`, count the occurrence of each `Med` in each group, then `spread` back to wide format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Change to 1:20 for your data (assuming all have prefix "Med"
thesecols <- sapply(1:3,function(x)paste0("Med",x))

df %>% 
  gather(key,value,thesecols) %>%
  group_by(AgeGroup, value) %>%
  summarise(count=sum(!is.na(value))) %>%
  spread(value, count)
```

Output

```
  AgeGroup   `6`   `9`    A1    A2    C2    C4    C5
1        1    NA     1     1     2    NA     1     1
2        2     1    NA     1    NA     1    NA    NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just encoutnered one problem. When I run this I get the following error message. Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  thesecols                                                         I looked online as to why this occurs but I am not sure I really understand what the remedy is. Could you point me in the correct direction?

Comment: > thesecols
[1] "ATC_101" "ATC_102" "ATC_103"

Comment: The vector of column names in `thesecols` contains an element that does not exist as a column in your data frame. Please show all column names in `thesecols` and `your data frame` or please make sure that all elements in `thesecols` are existent columns in your data frame

Comment: I believe they do. To get the column names to begin with all I did was thesecols = colnames(dataframe)[3:22] so they have to be existent columns .

Comment: Could you show output of `thesecols` and `colnames(dataframe)[3:22]`?

Comment: > colnames(df)[3:22]
 [1] "ATC_101"  "ATC_102"  "ATC_103"  "ATC_104"  "ATC_105"  "ATC_106"  "ATC_107"  "ATC_108"  "ATC_109" 
[10] "ATC_110"  "ATC_111A" "ATC_112A" "ATC_113A" "ATC_114A" "ATC_115A" "ATC_131A" "ATC_132A" "ATC_133A"
[19] "ATC_134A" "ATC_135A"

Comment: > thesecols
 [1] "ATC_101"  "ATC_102"  "ATC_103"  "ATC_104"  "ATC_105"  "ATC_106"  "ATC_107"  "ATC_108"  "ATC_109" 
[10] "ATC_110"  "ATC_111A" "ATC_112A" "ATC_113A" "ATC_114A" "ATC_115A" "ATC_131A" "ATC_132A" "ATC_133A"
[19] "ATC_134A" "ATC_135A"

Comment: Strange...could you try using only `thesecols[1]` first to see if you get the same error?

Comment: Could you try `thesecols <- "hp"` `mtcars %>% gather(key,value,thesecols)`? Error?

Comment: > thesecols <- "hp"
> mtcars %>%
+   gather(key,value,thesecols) %>%
+   group_by(AgeGroup, value) %>%
+   summarise(count=sum(!is.na(value))) %>%
+   spread(value, count)
Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  thesecols

Comment: Looks like it could be an issue with your `tidyr` maybe...which version are you using? Try updating to latest version and trying again?

Comment: I tried that didnt work. But I fiddled around with it and if I replace column names with c(ATC_101, ATC_102, ...) (no quotation marks around column names) it works! I'm not sure why but I checked by hand and it adds correctly.